# Screen freeze when an edittext is click inside a scrollview

Tags: android

More than 40 layout in a scrollview. when  click an edittext then screen freeze. how to resolve it.

Thanks,

Comment: Share Your Code..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problme and I solved it:

There were too many EditText's in the same LinearLayout. So I just divided them into 2 LinearLayout's and now it's good.

I don't know why but it works for me :)

Comment: thanks for your comment.. but i have near about 50 relativelayout and more than 10 edittext. when i click edittext then keyboard open and freeze the scrollview.

Comment: "50 relativelayout and more than 10 edittext" - that is your problem, you have a deeply nested view hierarchy that is being transversed, i.e. `requestLayout` when you click on the `EditText`. Refactor your code to have fewer nested view groups